# On a cpu with constant_tsc and nonstop_tsc, why does my time drift?

Tags: c++, linux, rdtsc

I am running this test on a cpu with `constant_tsc` and `nonstop_tsc`

```
$ grep -m 1 ^flags /proc/cpuinfo | sed 's/ /\n/g' | egrep "constant_tsc|nonstop_tsc"
constant_tsc
nonstop_tsc
```

**Step 1:** Calculate the tick rate of the tsc:

I calculate `_ticks_per_ns` as the median over a number of observations. I use `rdtscp` to ensure in-order execution.

```
static const int trials = 13;
std::array<double, trials> rates;

for (int i = 0; i < trials; ++i)
{
    timespec beg_ts, end_ts;
    uint64_t beg_tsc, end_tsc;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &beg_ts);
    beg_tsc = rdtscp();

    uint64_t elapsed_ns;
    do
    {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end_ts);
        end_tsc = rdtscp();

        elapsed_ns = to_ns(end_ts - beg_ts); // calculates ns between two timespecs
    }
    while (elapsed_ns < 10 * 1e6); // busy spin for 10ms

    rates[i] = (double)(end_tsc - beg_tsc) / (double)elapsed_ns;
}

std::nth_element(rates.begin(), rates.begin() + trials/2, rates.end());

_ticks_per_ns = rates[trials/2];
```

**Step 2:** Calculate starting wall clock time and tsc

```
uint64_t beg, end;
timespec ts;

// loop to ensure we aren't interrupted between the two tsc reads
while (1)
{
    beg = rdtscp();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
    end = rdtscp();

    if ((end - beg) <= 2000) // max ticks per clock call
        break;
}

_start_tsc        = end;
_start_clock_time = to_ns(ts); // converts timespec to ns since epoch
```

**Step 3:** Create a function which can return wall clock time from the tsc

```
uint64_t tsc_to_ns(uint64_t tsc)
{
    int64_t diff = tsc - _start_tsc;
    return _start_clock_time + (diff / _ticks_per_ns);
}
```

**Step 4:** Run in a loop, printing wallclock time from `clock_gettime` and from `rdtscp`

```
// lock the test to a single core
cpu_set_t mask;
CPU_ZERO(&mask);
CPU_SET(6, &mask);
sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &mask);

while (1)
{
    timespec utc_now;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &utc_now);
    uint64_t utc_ns = to_ns(utc_now);
    uint64_t tsc_ns = tsc_to_ns(rdtscp());

    uint64_t ns_diff = tsc_ns - utc_ns;

    std::cout << "clock_gettime " << ns_to_str(utc_ns) << '\n';
    std::cout << "tsc_time      " << ns_to_str(tsc_ns) << " diff=" << ns_diff << "ns\n";

    sleep(10);
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> clock_gettime 11:55:34.824419837
> tsc_time      11:55:34.824419840 diff=3ns
> clock_gettime 11:55:44.826260245
> tsc_time      11:55:44.826260736 diff=491ns
> clock_gettime 11:55:54.826516358
> tsc_time      11:55:54.826517248 diff=890ns
> clock_gettime 11:56:04.826683578
> tsc_time      11:56:04.826684672 diff=1094ns
> clock_gettime 11:56:14.826853056
> tsc_time      11:56:14.826854656 diff=1600ns
> clock_gettime 11:56:24.827013478
> tsc_time      11:56:24.827015424 diff=1946ns
> ```

**Questions:**

It is quickly evident that the times calculated in these two ways rapidly drift apart.

I'm assuming that with `constant_tsc` and `nonstop_tsc` that the tsc rate is constant.

- Is this the on board clock that is drifting? Surely it doesn't drift at this rate?
- What is the cause of this drift?
- Is there anything I can do to keep them in sync (other than very frequently recalculating `_start_tsc` and `_start_clock_time` in step 2)?

Comment: Depending on your env, you might get a better luck with  __vdso_clock_gettime function (you might need to load vdso and `dlsym` it).

Comment: Is your program locked to a single core? It's usually impossible to synchronize the TSC across cores exactly.

Comment: Based on your data, it looks like the mean "drift" rate between your wallclock time and TSC time is about 40 nanoseconds per second, or about 40 parts per billion. I suspect the main cause of this discrepancy is the limited accuracy of your ticks per nanosecond estimate. Actually, I'm pretty surprised that it's even that accurate.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen any tricks I can employ to increase the accuracy of my frequency calculation?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist I thought the whole point of `constant_tsc` was to keep the tscs synchronized across all cores in a system?

Comment: @SergeyA I'm running this test on Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.4.0-34-generic, glibc 2.23). Aren't I using vdso already?

Comment: No, `constant_tsc` means that the TSC ticks at a constant frequency independent of frequency scaling/TurboBoost/etc. For cores of the same make I'd imagine they'd tick at the same speed. But when each core actually starts its TSC ticking isn't synchronized, so between each core there will be an offset. Software can _attempt_ to synchronize the two, but you usually can't make them match to nanosecond precision.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist According to [this](http://btorpey.github.io/blog/2014/02/18/clock-sources-in-linux/) that is `nonstop_tsc`, but then I'm reading in the [intel manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.html) *Constant TSC behavior ensures that the duration of each clock tick is uniform and supports the use of the TSC as a wall clock timer even if the processor core changes frequency. This is the architectural behavior moving forward.* I will try my test with `taskset`

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist I've just used `sched_setaffinity` to lock it to a core - no difference

Comment: If `sched_setaffinity` would solve it, you'd probably [before that] have seen jitter up/down rather than steady drift. I have independent code for this with some 20 years mileage on it. I'm experimenting now. If I find something, I'll post [At present, my program confirms the drift]. BTW, the best value for CPU khz is derived from `bogomips / 2` rather than `/sys/...`

Comment: That link has `constant` and `nonstop` exactly inverted, and you should use Intel's terminology. As you found, constant TSC means constant period/frequency, and Intel's manual, immediately below in 17.14.1 Invariant TSC, describes the TSC as ticking regardless of sleep states, which is what that link should have called `nonstop`. But the asynchrony between the cores is apparently not the problem here.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist agreed, thanks for the input nonetheless!

Comment: I have some ideas, but it really depends on what the *actual* problem you're trying to solve by using the TSC as a wallclock timer is. (That said, most of my ideas basically boil down to using the TSC only to interpolate  or slightly extrapolate between regular actual wallclock timings.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen how often to you resync your starting wall clock time?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen *actual* problem is to find the absolute most performant way to get the current wall clock time. It's for our internal logging library. We have measured, it is a high contributor.

Comment: The drift seems accurate. Why not just use tsc_time for all log timestamps?

Comment: A few other things that come to mind are the following. 1) You should use a timebase much longer than 10*1e6 == 10e6 ns. Using a timebase of 10 ms, an error of just 1 ns gives you a skew of magnitude around 100 ns/s, and indeed your drift is of around that number, 40 ns/s. Bigger timebases correspond to smaller variance of estimate. 2) The conversion factor should be computed by iterating for a fixed amount of `tsc` ticks and computing the gap with `clock_gettime`; The reason being that `clock_gettime` is much more expensive than `rdtscp`. 3) You should subtract the overhead of `rdtscp`.

Comment: @SteveLorimer, Do you have any time synchronization daemon like ntpd enabled? What is the stratum of the ntp server used (and is it connected by stable network with symmetrical latency, not your Wifi)?  What is timesource of your REALTIME? What is your motherboard model, does it have TCXO quartz or any kind of DO (Disciplined oscillator) for CPU BCLK or it is just cheapest 100MHz and typical clock crystal, both having 20-50 ppm deviation. Is there "Spread-spectrum clock generation" (SSCG) in the motherboard to  limit EMI? You have 500ns / 10s it is less than 1 ppm, but you have to atomic clock

Comment: Another thing to consider: TSC could be adjusted at some point in time - e.g. by SMM - cf. https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/11/19/146

Answer (score 8):

The reason for the drift seen in the OP, at least on my machine, is that the TSC ticks per ns drifts away from its original value of `_ticks_per_ns`. The following results were from this machine:

```
don@HAL:~/UNIX/OS/3EZPcs/Ch06$ uname -a
Linux HAL 4.4.0-81-generic #104-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 14 08:17:06 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
don@HAL:~/UNIX/OS/3EZPcs/Ch06$  cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
tsc
```

`cat /proc/cpuinfo` shows `constant_tsc` and `nonstop_tsc` flags.

[image: Sample TSC Ticks per ns of clock_gettime() CLOCK_REALTIME vs. Time.]

viewRates.cc can be run to see the current TSC Ticks per ns on a machine:

rdtscp.h:

```
static inline unsigned long rdtscp_start(void) {
  unsigned long var;
  unsigned int hi, lo;
  
  __asm volatile ("cpuid\n\t"
          "rdtsc\n\t" : "=a" (lo), "=d" (hi)
          :: "%rbx", "%rcx");
  
  var = ((unsigned long)hi << 32) | lo;
  return (var);
}

static inline unsigned long rdtscp_end(void) {
  unsigned long var;
  unsigned int hi, lo;
  
  __asm volatile ("rdtscp\n\t"
          "mov %%edx, %1\n\t"
          "mov %%eax, %0\n\t"
          "cpuid\n\t"  : "=r" (lo), "=r" (hi)
          :: "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
  
  var = ((unsigned long)hi << 32) | lo;
  return (var);
  }
```

See: Intel's [ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/embedded/training/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.html)

viewRates.cc:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "rdtscp.h"
using std::cout;  using std::cerr;  using std::endl;

#define CLOCK CLOCK_REALTIME

uint64_t to_ns(const timespec &ts);   // Converts a struct timespec to ns (since epoch).
void view_ticks_per_ns(int runs =10, int sleep =10);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int runs = 10, sleep = 10;
  if (argc != 1 && argc != 3) {
    cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " [ RUNS SLEEP ] \n";
    exit(1);
  } else if (argc == 3) {
    runs = std::atoi(argv[1]);
    sleep = std::atoi(argv[2]);
  }

  view_ticks_per_ns(runs, sleep); 
}

  void view_ticks_per_ns(int RUNS, int SLEEP) {
// Prints out stream of RUNS tsc ticks per ns, each calculated over a SLEEP secs interval.
  timespec clock_start, clock_end;
  unsigned long tsc1, tsc2, tsc_start, tsc_end;
  unsigned long elapsed_ns, elapsed_ticks;
  double rate; // ticks per ns from each run.

  clock_getres(CLOCK, &clock_start);
  cout <<  "Clock resolution: " << to_ns(clock_start) << "ns\n\n";

  cout << " tsc ticks      " << "ns      " << " tsc ticks per ns\n";
  for (int i = 0; i < RUNS; ++i) {
    tsc1 = rdtscp_start();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK, &clock_start);
    tsc2 = rdtscp_end();                      
    tsc_start = (tsc1 + tsc2) / 2;

    sleep(SLEEP);

    tsc1 = rdtscp_start();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK, &clock_end);
    tsc2 = rdtscp_end();                     
    tsc_end = (tsc1 + tsc2) / 2;
    
    elapsed_ticks = tsc_end - tsc_start;
    elapsed_ns = to_ns(clock_end) - to_ns(clock_start);
    rate = static_cast<double>(elapsed_ticks) / elapsed_ns;

    cout << elapsed_ticks << " " << elapsed_ns << " " << std::setprecision(12) << rate << endl;
  } 
}
```

linearExtrapolator.cc can be run to re-create the experiment of the OP:

linearExtrapolator.cc:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include "rdtscp.h"

using std::cout;  using std::endl;  using std::array;

#define CLOCK CLOCK_REALTIME

uint64_t to_ns(const timespec &ts);   // Converts a struct timespec to ns (since epoch).
void set_ticks_per_ns(bool set_rate); // Display or set tsc ticks per ns, _ticks_per_ns.
void get_start();             // Sets the 'start' time point: _start_tsc[in ticks] and _start_clock_time[in ns].
uint64_t tsc_to_ns(uint64_t tsc);     // Convert tsc ticks since _start_tsc to ns (since epoch) linearly using
                                      // _ticks_per_ns with origin(0) at the 'start' point set by get_start().

uint64_t _start_tsc, _start_clock_time; // The 'start' time point as both tsc tick number, start_tsc, and as
                                        // clock_gettime ns since epoch as _start_clock_time.
double _ticks_per_ns;                   // Calibrated in set_ticks_per_ns()

int main() {
  set_ticks_per_ns(true); // Set _ticks_per_ns as the initial TSC ticks per ns.

  uint64_t tsc1, tsc2, tsc_now, tsc_ns, utc_ns;
  int64_t ns_diff;
  bool first_pass{true};
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    timespec utc_now;
    if (first_pass) {
      get_start(); //Get start time in both ns since epoch (_start_clock_time), and tsc tick number(_start_tsc)
      cout << "_start_clock_time: " <<  _start_clock_time << ", _start_tsc: " << _start_tsc << endl;
      utc_ns = _start_clock_time;
      tsc_ns = tsc_to_ns(_start_tsc);   // == _start_clock_time by definition.
      tsc_now = _start_tsc;
      first_pass = false;
    } else {
      tsc1 = rdtscp_start();
      clock_gettime(CLOCK, &utc_now);
      tsc2 = rdtscp_end();
      tsc_now = (tsc1 + tsc2) / 2;
      tsc_ns = tsc_to_ns(tsc_now);
      utc_ns = to_ns(utc_now);
    }

    ns_diff = tsc_ns - (int64_t)utc_ns;
    
    cout << "elapsed ns: " << utc_ns - _start_clock_time << ", elapsed ticks: " << tsc_now - _start_tsc 
     << ", ns_diff: " << ns_diff << '\n' << endl;
    
    set_ticks_per_ns(false);  // Display current TSC ticks per ns (does not alter original _ticks_per_ns).
  }
}

void set_ticks_per_ns(bool set_rate) {
  constexpr int RUNS {1}, SLEEP{10};
  timespec clock_start, clock_end;
  uint64_t tsc1, tsc2, tsc_start, tsc_end;
  uint64_t elapsed_ns[RUNS], elapsed_ticks[RUNS];
  array<double, RUNS> rates; // ticks per ns from each run.

  if (set_rate) {
    clock_getres(CLOCK, &clock_start);
    cout <<  "Clock resolution: " << to_ns(clock_start) << "ns\n";
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < RUNS; ++i) {
    tsc1 = rdtscp_start();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK, &clock_start);
    tsc2 = rdtscp_end();                      
    tsc_start = (tsc1 + tsc2) / 2;

    sleep(SLEEP);

    tsc1 = rdtscp_start();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK, &clock_end);
    tsc2 = rdtscp_end();                     
    tsc_end = (tsc1 + tsc2) / 2;
    
    elapsed_ticks[i] = tsc_end - tsc_start;
    elapsed_ns[i] = to_ns(clock_end) - to_ns(clock_start);
    rates[i] = static_cast<double>(elapsed_ticks[i]) / elapsed_ns[i];
  }
  
  cout << " tsc ticks      " << "ns     " << "tsc ticks per ns" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < RUNS; ++i)
    cout << elapsed_ticks[i] << " " << elapsed_ns[i] << " " << std::setprecision(12) << rates[i] << endl;

  if (set_rate)
    _ticks_per_ns = rates[RUNS-1];
}

constexpr uint64_t BILLION {1000000000};

uint64_t to_ns(const timespec &ts) {
  return ts.tv_sec * BILLION + ts.tv_nsec;
}

void get_start() { // Get start time both in tsc ticks as _start_tsc, and in ns since epoch as _start_clock_time
  timespec ts;
  uint64_t beg, end;

// loop to ensure we aren't interrupted between the two tsc reads
  while (1) {
    beg = rdtscp_start();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK, &ts);
    end = rdtscp_end();   
    if ((end - beg) <= 2000) // max ticks per clock call
      break;
  }

  _start_tsc = (end + beg) / 2;
  _start_clock_time = to_ns(ts); // converts timespec to ns since epoch
}

uint64_t tsc_to_ns(uint64_t tsc) { // Convert tsc ticks into absolute ns:
  // Absolute ns is defined by this linear extrapolation from the start point where
  //_start_tsc[in ticks] corresponds to _start_clock_time[in ns].
  uint64_t diff = tsc - _start_tsc;
  return _start_clock_time + static_cast<uint64_t>(diff / _ticks_per_ns);
}
```

Here is output from a run of `viewRates` immediately followed by `linearExtrapolator`:

```
# ./viewRates 

Clock resolution: 1ns

 tsc ticks      ns       tsc ticks per ns
28070466526 10000176697 2.8069970538
28070500272 10000194599 2.80699540335
28070489661 10000196097 2.80699392179
28070404159 10000170879 2.80699245029
28070464811 10000197285 2.80699110338
28070445753 10000195177 2.80698978932
28070430538 10000194298 2.80698851457
28070427907 10000197673 2.80698730414
28070409903 10000195492 2.80698611597
28070398177 10000195328 2.80698498942

# ./linearExtrapolator

Clock resolution: 1ns
 tsc ticks      ns     tsc ticks per ns
28070385587 10000197480 2.8069831264
_start_clock_time: 1497966724156422794, _start_tsc: 4758879747559
elapsed ns: 0, elapsed ticks: 0, ns_diff: 0

 tsc ticks      ns     tsc ticks per ns
28070364084 10000193633 2.80698205596
elapsed ns: 10000247486, elapsed ticks: 28070516229, ns_diff: -3465

 tsc ticks      ns     tsc ticks per ns
28070358445 10000195130 2.80698107188
elapsed ns: 20000496849, elapsed ticks: 56141027929, ns_diff: -10419

 tsc ticks      ns     tsc ticks per ns
28070350693 10000195646 2.80698015186
elapsed ns: 30000747550, elapsed ticks: 84211534141, ns_diff: -20667

 tsc ticks      ns     tsc ticks per ns
28070324772 10000189692 2.80697923105
elapsed ns: 40000982325, elapsed ticks: 112281986547, ns_diff: -34158

 tsc ticks      ns     tsc ticks per ns
28070340494 10000198352 2.80697837242
elapsed ns: 50001225563, elapsed ticks: 140352454025, ns_diff: -50742

 tsc ticks      ns     tsc ticks per ns
28070325598 10000196057 2.80697752704
elapsed ns: 60001465937, elapsed ticks: 168422905017, ns_diff: -70335

# ^C
```

The `viewRates` output shows that the TSC ticks per ns are decreasing fairly rapidly with time corresponding to one of those steep drops in the plot above. The `linearExtrapolator` output shows, as in the OP, the difference between the elapsed ns as reported by `clock_gettime()`, and the elapsed ns obtained by converting the elapsed TSC ticks to elapsed ns using `_ticks_per_ns` == 2.8069831264 obtained at start time. Rather than a `sleep(10);` between each print out of `elapsed ns`, `elapsed ticks`, `ns_diff`, I re-run the TSC ticks per ns calculation using a 10s window; this prints out the current `tsc ticks per ns` ratio. It can be seen that the trend of decreasing TSC ticks per ns observed from the `viewRates` output is continuing throughout the run of `linearExtrapolator`.

Dividing an `elapsed ticks` by `_ticks_per_ns` and subtracting the corresponding `elapsed ns` gives the `ns_diff`, e.g.: (84211534141 / 2.8069831264) - 30000747550 = -20667. But this is not 0 mainly due the drift in TSC ticks per ns. If we had used a value of 2.80698015186 ticks per ns obtained from the last 10s interval, the result would be: (84211534141 / 2.80698015186) - 30000747550 = 11125. The additional error accumulated during that last 10s interval, -20667 - -10419 = -10248, nearly disappears when the correct TSC ticks per ns value is used for that interval: (84211534141 - 56141027929) /  2.80698015186 - (30000747550 - 20000496849) = 349.

If the linearExtrapolator had been run at a time when the TSC ticks per ns had been constant, the accuracy would be limited by how well the (constant) `_ticks_per_ns` had been determined, and then it would pay to take, e.g., a median of several estimates. If the `_ticks_per_ns` was off by a fixed 40 parts per billion, a constant drift of about 400ns every 10 seconds would be expected, so `ns_diff` would grow/shrink by 400 each 10 seconds.

genTimeSeriesofRates.cc can be used to generate data for a plot like above:
genTimeSeriesofRates.cc:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include "rdtscp.h"

using std::cout;  using std::cerr;  using std::endl;  using std::array;

double get_ticks_per_ns(long &ticks, long &ns); // Get median tsc ticks per ns, ticks and ns.
long ts_to_ns(const timespec &ts);

#define CLOCK CLOCK_REALTIME            // clock_gettime() clock to use.
#define TIMESTEP 10
#define NSTEPS  10000
#define RUNS 5            // Number of RUNS and SLEEP interval used for each sample in get_ticks_per_ns().
#define SLEEP 1

int main() {
  timespec ts;
  clock_getres(CLOCK, &ts);
  cerr << "CLOCK resolution: " << ts_to_ns(ts) << "ns\n";
  
  clock_gettime(CLOCK, &ts);
  int start_time = ts.tv_sec;

  double ticks_per_ns;
  int running_elapsed_time = 0; //approx secs since start_time to center of the sampling done by get_ticks_per_ns()
  long ticks, ns;
  for (int timestep = 0; timestep < NSTEPS; ++timestep) {
    clock_gettime(CLOCK, &ts);
    ticks_per_ns = get_ticks_per_ns(ticks, ns);
    running_elapsed_time = ts.tv_sec - start_time + RUNS * SLEEP / 2;
    
    cout << running_elapsed_time << ' ' << ticks << ' ' << ns << ' ' 
     << std::setprecision(12) << ticks_per_ns << endl;
    
    sleep(10);
  }
}

double get_ticks_per_ns(long &ticks, long &ns) {
  // get the median over RUNS runs of elapsed tsc ticks, CLOCK ns, and their ratio over a SLEEP secs time interval 
  timespec clock_start, clock_end;
  long tsc_start, tsc_end;
  array<long, RUNS> elapsed_ns, elapsed_ticks;
  array<double, RUNS> rates; // arrays from each run from which to get medians.

  for (int i = 0; i < RUNS; ++i) {
    clock_gettime(CLOCK, &clock_start);
    tsc_start = rdtscp_end(); // minimizes time between clock_start and tsc_start.
    sleep(SLEEP);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK, &clock_end);
    tsc_end = rdtscp_end();
    
    elapsed_ticks[i] = tsc_end - tsc_start;
    elapsed_ns[i] = ts_to_ns(clock_end) - ts_to_ns(clock_start);
    rates[i] = static_cast<double>(elapsed_ticks[i]) / elapsed_ns[i];
  }

  // get medians:
  std::nth_element(elapsed_ns.begin(), elapsed_ns.begin() + RUNS/2, elapsed_ns.end());
  std::nth_element(elapsed_ticks.begin(), elapsed_ticks.begin() + RUNS/2, elapsed_ticks.end());
  std::nth_element(rates.begin(), rates.begin() + RUNS/2, rates.end());
  ticks = elapsed_ticks[RUNS/2];
  ns = elapsed_ns[RUNS/2];

  return rates[RUNS/2];
}

constexpr long BILLION {1000000000};

long ts_to_ns(const timespec &ts) {
  return ts.tv_sec * BILLION + ts.tv_nsec;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, but I would like to understand: (a) Why you are using separate *inline* statements (in `rdtscp.h`) for reading the *start* vs *end* TS's? (b) Why are you using `RDTSC` in one and then `RDTSCP` in the other end read? (c) What SW did you use to create the plot?

Answer (score 4):

The relationship between the TSC and something like `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` will not be exactly unchanging. Even though you "calibrate" the TSC against `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, the calibration will be out of date almost as soon as it is finished!

The reasons they won't stay in sync long term:

1. `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is affected by NTP clock rate adjustments. NTP will constantly check network time and subtly slow down or speed up the system clock to match network time. This results in some kind of oscillating pattern in the true `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` frequency, and so your calibration will always be slightly off, especially the next time NTP applies a rate adjustment. You could compare against `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` to eliminate this effect.
2. `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` and TSC are almost certainly based on *totally different underlying oscillators*. It is often say that modern OSes use the TSC for time-keeping, but this is only to apply a small "local" offset to some other underlying slow-running clock to provide a very precise time (e.g., the "slow time" might be updated every timer tick, and then the TSC is used to interpolate between timer ticks). It is the slow underlying clock (something like the HPET or APIC clocks) that determines the longer-term behavior of `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`. The TSC itself, however is an independent free running clock, deriving its frequency from a different oscillator, on a different place on the chipset/motherboard and will different natural fluctuations (in particular, different response to temperature changes).

It is (2) that is more fundamental out of the two above: it means that even without any kind of NTP adjustments (or if you use a clock that is not subject to them), you'll see drift over time if the underlying clocks are based on different physical oscillators.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the on board clock that is drifting? Surely it doesn't drift at this rate?
No, they shouldn't drift

What is the cause of this drift?
NTP service or similar that runs your OS. They affects clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, ...);

Is there anything I can do to keep them in sync (other than very frequently recalculating _start_tsc and _start_clock_time in step 2)?
Yes you can ease the problem.

1 You can try to use CLOCK_MONOTONIC instead of CLOCK_REALTIME.

2 You can calculate the difference as a linear function from the time and apply it to compensate the drifting. But it will not be very reliable because time services doesn't adjust the time as linear function. But it will give you some more accuracy. Periodically you can do readjustment.

---

Some drifting you can get because you calculate _ticks_per_ns not accurately. You can check it by running you program several times. If results are not reproducible, it is mean that you calculate your _ticks_per_ns incorrectly. It is better to use statistics method then just an average value.

---

Also please note, _ticks_per_ns you are calculating by using CLOCK_MONOTONIC, which is related to TSC.

Next you are using CLOCK_REALTIME. It provides the system time. If your system has NTP or similar service, the time will be adjusted.

Your difference is around 2 micro seconds per minute. It is 0.002 * 24*60 = 2.9 milli seconds a day. It is a great accuracy for CPU clock. 3 ms a day it is a 1 second a year.

[image]

Comment: BayK, is tsc clock affected/modulated by ["Spread-spectrum clock generation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spread_spectrum) (SSCG) or not? Where is the linux kernel interface (in `/proc` or in `/sys`) to see current adjust parameters if they are set by NTP or other time daemon?

Comment: (There is SSCG in Xeon Phi's `micetc`: https://books.google.com/books?id=KJORYTHOxbEC&pg=PA380 Intel Xeon Phi Coprocessor High Performance Programming, 9780124104945, page 380. Also https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/virtual/kvm/timekeeping.txt - ".. very large systems may deliberately slew the clocks of individual
cores  This technique, known as spread-spectrum clocking, reduces EMI at the clock frequency and harmonics of it". There was SSC in FSB - http://serverfault.com/questions/129112/)

Comment: Osgx, NTP or other time daemon can't adjust TSC.  It affects what clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME) function return. In this question code shows difference between clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME) result and tsc clock.